# Protocol 'Shape' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Tags: swift, swiftui

In an attempt to create my abstractions:

```
protocol ElectricallyDrawable {
    func isConnected() -> Bool

    func showPowerAnimation(using shape: Shape) <-- Error
}
```

`Protocol 'Shape' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Firstly I know this question has been asked **umptillion** times.

I understand the error and had I known `Shape` had an `associatedtype` I would have expected this..

So..

**I'm not asking why I'm getting this error**

rather my question is:

**How is one supposed to figure out the `associatedtype` of each `protocol`**

Because I have searched the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shape), and the definition and nothing.

If we knew the `associatedtype` nomenclature then we could set it in our concrete type.. for example..

If I knew:

```
protocol Shape {
      associatedtype Line 
}
```

I could then use it like:

```
protocol ElectricallyDrawable {
    typealias Line = Rectangle <-- This would stop the error 
    
    func isConnected() -> Bool

    func showPowerAnimation(using shape: Shape) 
}
```

Comment: What you need is a generic method `func showPowerAnimation<S: Shape>(using shape: S)`. What is `Rectangle`? You haven't shown its declaration. Replace`typealias Line = Rectangle` with `associatedtype Line`

Comment: typealias should be inside your struct/class that conform to Shape

Comment: @LeoDabus So would I be able to pass in a shape at the call site of `showPowerAnimation` and yes, that is my mistake it should be in a concrete type, like a `struct`

Comment: Your comment combined with the answer below makes things clearer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm going to answer two questions

**1) How are you supposed to get the `associatedtype` of a protocol?**

There are two options. Option a: You are implementing the interface:

```swift
struct Resistor: ElectricallyDrawable {
    typealias Line = Rectangle
}
```

In this case, it's implicitly clear that your line is a rectangle, since you define it.

Option b: You are extending the interface:

```swift
extension ElectricallyDrawable where Line == Rectangle {
    //...
}
```

or

```swift
extension ElectricallyDrawable {
    func x() {
        if Line.self == Rectangle.self {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

So in either way, you simply 'get' the `associatedtype` by its name.

**2) How would you actually do this?**

Well, there are two options. You can either go the `associatedtype` way like so:

```swift
protocol ElectricallyDrawable {
    
    associatedtype Line: Shape
    
    func isConnected() -> Bool

    func showPowerAnimation(using shape: Line)
}
```

Where you constrain yourself that the `associatedtype` (the actual type you're using) is a shape, or you add a generic to the function itself:

```swift
protocol ElectricallyDrawable {

    func isConnected() -> Bool

    func showPowerAnimation<S>(using shape: S) where S: Shape
}
```

either way is fine and the best approach probably depends on your use-case

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things a lot